# Given in de Sitter space time is frozen on the horizon, can we say that in anti-de Sitter space time goes infinitely fast at the space boundary?

Tags: event-horizon, anti-de-sitter-spacetime, de-sitter-spacetime

Particularly, in de Sitter space everything on the cosmic event horizon is redshifted, while in anti-de Sitter space everything on the horizon is blueshifted.

Comment: Perhaps an even simpler example is the Schwarzschild event horizon. At this horizon, time on its outer age is $t$ and it is frozen or moves with a zero speed (equivalently, the speed of light there is asymptotically zero) $dt/dr\to 0$. However, on the inner edge of the same horizon, time is $r$ and it moves with an infinite speed (equivalently, the speed of light there is asymptotically infinite) $dr/dt\to\infty$. With two different asymptotic limits on two sides, the speed of light (or of anything) at the horizon is undefined. See section 3 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.3619.pdf

Comment: @safesphere if you are inside an infinitely blueshifted horizon, are not you immediately incinerated by the radiation coming from the horizon, as it would have infinite temperature?

Comment: No, because you are also moving with an asymptotically infinite speed making the radiation redshifted relative to you (at least the radial portion of it). I believe it works out that an observer free falling from infinity sees the universe redshifted twice in the radial direction at the horizon whether inside or outside.

Comment: @safesphere I do not see how in AdS space the radiation is redshifted

Comment: No, sorry, I was still talking about my Schwarzschild example anove, not AdS.